# Difficulty deploying front end app to google app engine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-app-engine, webpack, deployment

I am trying to deploy an app to  google app engine  but every time I deploy it only reads the index.html file and the  and the bundled.js files dont seem to run

```
    devtool: 'source-map',
    context: __dirname,
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        index: './index.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.worker\.js$/],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            cacheDirectory: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.worker\.js$/,
                use: ['worker-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.global\.less$/],
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: {
                                exportLocalsConvention: 'camelCase',
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    'less-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.global\.less$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                include: [/node_modules/],
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'less-loader',
                        options: {
                            lessOptions: {
                                modifyVars: antdTheme,
                                javascriptEnabled: true,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(diff|raw)$/,
                use: ['raw-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
        modules: ['node_modules'],
        alias: {
            'TOOL': path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src'),
            'mapbox-gl$': path.resolve('./node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js'),
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'TOOL',
        }),
    ],
    devServer: {
        port: 8080,
        open: true,
        inline: true,
        hot: false,
    },
};
```

This is the server I am using to host the application but it never seems to run when I am use it on google app engine I have got it to run on firebase and it works fine locally but I am having a lot of difficulty getting it to run on a server. And I am not sure how I am meant to do this correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
const path = require('path')
const app = require('api-engine')();

const { PORT = 8080 } = process.env;

app.use('/', (req, res) => { 
    return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
 });

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.info(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I also get this error when I try to deploy it on my server locally

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Comment: Is it `bundle.js`, or `bundled.js`?  Where is `bundle.js` located in relation to this file?  Try putting the relative path in `filename: 'bundle.js',`

Comment: @john Is the issue resolved?

Comment: @divyaniYadav yes it is ill upload the solution in a moment

Comment: @john Can you upload the solution, it would be helpful.